# How to send value from Jquery page to Jsp page using AJAX?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am passing a string variable from my jquery page using AJAX and want it to be retrieved in my jsp page. Although, it shows "null" when I print it on the jsp.

Am I missing some import on the jsp page for the `request.getParameter` to run properly?

My Jquery:

```
var samname = thisValue; 
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "/Program.jsp", 
  data: samname,
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
    //  result = samname;
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert("error"); 
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }  
  //   return samname;
  //also check return false at bottom;
});
```

My JSP:

```
String value = "";
value = request.getParameter("name");

out.println(value);
```

Comment: What is `thisValue`???

Comment: thisValue is assigned with the name attribute of a select tag. I need it to be present in my jsp code, everytime it changes (the jquery I have posted is a fragment from the onchange function)

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery code to this code. This must work:

Jquery:

```
var samname = thisValue; 
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "/Program.jsp", 
  data: {name:samname}, //pass this parameter like this then you will be able to get it there
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
    //  result = samname;
  },
  error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
    alert("error"); 
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }  
  //   return samname;
  //also check return false at bottom;
});
```

Comment: Goes to the error area :( You sure that I can retrieve directly to jsp?

Comment: yes , Then you can get the "name" parameter there. You will get the name parameter ther but not sure why this comes to error function. Show us your more code, Then we might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the ajax data:

Instead of:

```
 data: samname,
```

Try this

```
 data: {'name' : samname},
```